# Plotting lines with for loop (accuracy and batch size)

Tags: python, for-loop, plot, data-visualization, line-plot

I am quite new to python and coding as well.

I have two nested for loops like sample as below.

```
for x in range(1,10):
    .....
    for y in range(1,10):
        .....
```

In the second loop I calculate accuracy scores and in the first loop batch size is changing.

Is there anyway to plot lines of accuracy for each batch size in same graph with color difference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need more information. A minimal working example for example

Comment: You will need a plotting library.
Use numpy + matplotlib
https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py